# in "node:vm" when context is array how access the keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, read-eval-print-loop

How to access the key on the context when using `node:vm` module with `context` that is an instance of Array. Because as using numbers just `vm` just `eval` the number and return it back

```js
import vm from 'node:vm';
var context = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}];
var cmd = '0'
vm.runInNewContext(cmd, context); // return 0;
```

That approach can work:

```
cmd = 'this[0]'
vm.runInNewContext(cmd, context); // return {a:1};
```

But, are there a better way to access the keys on the array just by name like in a normal context's object?

Comment: A better way would be to use an object as context. The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vmruninnewcontextcode-contextobject-options) also suggests that context should be an object.

Comment: I build something that needs to operate on objects and an object's array intermittently

Answer (score 0):

If the target is an array, can't you just do the actual indexing into it outside the `vm` call?

```
import vm from 'node:vm';
const arr = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}];
var cmd = '1 - 1';
const index = vm.runInNewContext(cmd);
if(typeof index !== 'number' || index < 0 || index >= arr.length) throw new Error("oh no");
const value = arr[index];
```

Comment: That nice, I got to similar solution, the ` vm.runInNewContext(cmd)` is a nice touch. in my code, I decided that if the user does not put a direct number it does not mention the key on the array.